# Regex Find/Replace in Notepad++ including new lines

Tags: regex, notepad++

Need to replace/remove multiple occurrences in notepad++ using regex.
Here is an example:

```
....
something<item>text to be removed or replaced</item>
text<item>another text to be
removed or replaced</item>
<item>more text to be removed or 
replaced</item>
...
```

I need to replace/remove everything in between `"<item>"` and `"</item>"`, matches could include a new line.

So I would end up with something like this:

```
....
something<item></item>
text<item></item>
<item></item>
...
```

Comment: The word `text` bellow `something` is not inside a `<item></item>`, but in output text, it does not appear. `text` does not may appear in the result?

Comment: You are right, my fault. Will edit my OP. Thanks

Comment: forgot to say: the answer was tested on `Notepad++ v6.8.8` :)

Comment: Find:  (>).*(<)   replace with: $1$2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to do this *find/replace*:

Find what: `(<item>).*?(<\/item>)\R?`

Replace with: `$1$2`

Check the `Matches new line` checkbox.

[image]

More information: [Notepad++ User Manual - Regular Expressions](https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/searching/#regular-expressions)